# trace route from my position to a location google maps v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with plotting a route from my position to a certain position , I need to take my latitude and longitude of the origin variable and simply attached code to see if someone manages to solve
try to leave the values ​​in other variables , leaving them in a marker , among other ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

    <script>
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
// is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

var map;

function initialize() {
    var pos;
    var latitud;
    var longitud;
    var dirinicial;
                       
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
   
  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
        //var hola = pos;
        latitud = position.coords.latitude;
        longitud = position.coords.longitude;
 
   /* var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  
  */
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
       // content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });            
      map.setCenter(pos);
       
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });

  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
   var request = {
       origin:'Santiago', 
       destination: 'Rancagua',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };   
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    /*     // Display the distance:
         document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";

         // Display the duration:
         document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
*/
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
   });
}

        function GetAddress(latlang) {
        
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud);
     var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        dirinicial= results[1].formatted_address;
                        //alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }
        
        
function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance
regards from chile!

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors here. First, your error management displays an infowindow at a random location {lat:60, lng:105} that's not related to the user eventual position.

Second, your route request has fixed origin and destination (Santiago and Rancagua), disregarding the user's current location at all. You should instead wait for the HTML5 geolocation API to return something to use as origin.

I've simplified your code a bit, and got this working

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var pos;
    var latitud;
    var longitud;
    var dirinicial;

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);

    var generateRoute=function(origin,destination) {
        var request = {
           origin:origin, 
           destination: destination,
           travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };   

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    };

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,  position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        }); 

        var yourpositionmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:pos, map:map});

        infowindow.open(map,yourpositionmarker);
        map.setCenter(pos);
        generateRoute(pos, 'Rancagua');
    });

  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    console.log('No geolocation API');
  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```